# How do you test multi-step time series forecasting?

Tags: time-series, forecasting

Suppose you have **n** observations of a time series dataset. You split it up to
**n-k** (train data) and **k** (test data) observations. You train a model using
the train data and you can now make predictions. From what I understand multi-step
forecasting means you want to predict the next **q>1** observations. So you predict
with your model the next **q** observations and you use a metric to compare them with their
respective values from the test data. Now for the next step, will you need to train a new model
which will also include the first **q** values from the test data and repeat the same process?

Comment: How is this a duplicate?